# SSH timeout error when building AWS AMI with Vagrant

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant

I am trying to setup an AWS AMI vagrant provision: http://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html

I am using the standard `.json` config:

```
{
  "type": "amazon-instance",
  "access_key": "YOUR KEY HERE",
  "secret_key": "YOUR SECRET KEY HERE",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "source_ami": "ami-d9d6a6b0",
  "instance_type": "m1.small",
  "ssh_username": "ubuntu",

  "account_id": "0123-4567-0890",
  "s3_bucket": "packer-images",
  "x509_cert_path": "x509.cert",
  "x509_key_path": "x509.key",
  "x509_upload_path": "/tmp",

  "ami_name": "packer-quick-start {{timestamp}}"
}
```

It connects fine, and I see it create the instance in my AWS account. However, I keep getting `Timeout waiting for SSH` as an error. What could be causing this problem and how can I resolve it?

Comment: I use packer.io as well... this error just seems to happen sometimes... I think mainly because the launching of an amazon instance can be a little unpredictable time wise. I just keep trying until it finds an ssh connection... not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment above this is just because sometimes it takes more than a minute for an instance to launch and be SSH ready.

If you want you could set the timeout to be longer - the default timeout with packer is 1 minute.

So you could set it to 5 minutes by adding the following to your json config:

```
"ssh_timeout": "5m"
```